# oracle sql query joining a table with existing query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following four tables with the following structures

**Table A**

```
  ColA1  ColA2  ColA3    ColA4  ColA5
-----------------------------------------
  AA     100      CC     DD       EE
```

**Table B**

```
  ColB1  ColB2  ColB3    ColB4   ColB5
 -------------------------------------------
 AA      100     40452   A9       CDE
```

when these `two tables` were joined like the following:

```
 Select colA1,ColA2, ColA3, ColA4, ColB3,ColB4, ColB5
   from table A
        Left outer join 
            (select ColB3, ColB4, ColB5
              from table B
              where colB3 = (select max(colB3) from table B
            )
          on (colA1 = colB1 and ColA2 = col B2);
```

Now i have to join the next `table C` with `table B`

**Table C** structure is

```
 ColD1   ColD2   ColD3
 --------------------------------  
  Desc1 A9   Executive
  Desc1 A7   Engineer
```

I have the common column such as `ColD2 and colB4` to get the `Col D3`

how do i join the `existing query + join between` table b and table c?

Answer (score 0):

*Not tested but it would be something like given below*

```
 SELECT colA1,ColA2, ColA3, ColA4, ColB3,ColB4, ColB5,ColD3
   FROM table A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            (SELECT ColB3, ColB4, ColB5
              FROM table B
              WHERE colB3 = (SELECT MAX(colB3) FROM table B
            )
          ON (colA1 = colB1 AND ColA2 = col B2)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE C
          ON (colB4=colD2);
```